# Imports failed in Config.groovy file (Grails 2.2.3)

Tags: grails, import

I try to run a grails app thanks to `grails run-app` command. Version I use is grails 2.2.3.
All imports failed and I've got the "unable to resolve class" about all import line. For example : 
`unable to resolve class com.octo.captcha.component.image.backgroundgenerator.GradientBackgroundGenerator`

Errors are about the following lines :

```
import com.octo.captcha.service.multitype.GenericManageableCaptchaService
import com.octo.captcha.engine.GenericCaptchaEngine
import com.octo.captcha.image.gimpy.GimpyFactory
import com.octo.captcha.component.word.wordgenerator.RandomWordGenerator
import com.octo.captcha.component.image.wordtoimage.ComposedWordToImage
import com.octo.captcha.component.image.fontgenerator.RandomFontGenerator
import com.octo.captcha.component.image.backgroundgenerator.GradientBackgroundGenerator
import com.octo.captcha.component.image.color.SingleColorGenerator
import com.octo.captcha.component.image.textpaster.NonLinearTextPaster
```

Here you can read these 2 files : Config.groovy and the return of "grails run-app" to help you : http://dl.free.fr/vPbCJEUnN

Thanks for your help !

Comment: did you install the jcaptcha plugin?

Comment: Are you dependencies properly configured in BuildConfig.groovy ?
Paste relevant parts of your BuildConfig.groovy here

Comment: It's look like you missed the command "grails install-plugin jcaptcha"

Comment: also try to call `grails refresh-dependencies`